# what is the cause of NSInternalInconsistencyException and how to resolve it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting this error on resetting the frame of collection view (summaryView) in this method

```
- (void)configureSubviews{

    _close.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, 10 , 51, 35);

    [_close setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [_close setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [_close setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [_close addTarget:self action:@selector(closeDetailView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self addSubview:_close];

    _dragger.frame = CGRectMake((rect.size.width-35)/2, 28, 23, 10);

    _dragger.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"summary_dragger_portrait.png"];

    _draggerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, 40);

    _contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 13, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

    [_summaryView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

    _summaryView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, rect.size.width, rect.size.height-93);// exception occurs on this line

    _borderView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 36, rect.size.width, 0.5);

    actionX = rect.size.width-41;

}
```

> **Exception:**
>
> MyApp[2585:728612] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData
>   validateLayoutInRect:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3512.60.12/UICollectionViewData.m:408
>   2016-08-11 11:22:05.175 MyApp [2585:728612] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'layout
>   attributes for supplementary item at index path ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) changed from
>    index path:
>   ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); element kind:
>   (SummarySuppView); frame = (6 0; 743 65); zIndex = -1;  to
>    index path:
>   ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); element kind:
>   (SummarySuppView); frame = (6 0; 743 65); zIndex = -1;  without
>   invalidating the layout'

This method is called from animation block

```
UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.15
                       options:        (UIViewAnimationOptions)UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp 
                    animations:^ {
                        [self layoutDataViewsForSize:listSize];
                        [self layoutSummaryViewsForSize:summarySize];

                         [_summaryView layoutSubviews]; // method call
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        if (_filterActions.alpha==0) {
                            _filterActions.alpha= 1.0f;
                        }
                    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you change layout and not call invalidate in all views in it.  Try to call super in layoutSubviews, it may help

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
   [super layoutSubviews];
  ...your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
 {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [viewCollection.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

Comment: Please see the recent edits.That method name was confusing, sorry for that. I have already invalidate the layout "[_summaryView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];"

Comment: Add the code you are using for number of sections and how are you making the UICollectionView cells and you are using somethinng as SummarySuppView